# Extracting Specific numbers from text on Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter

The data is as in the form below. I am trying to extract the hour(h), and minute(m) from the text to calculate the total duration in google sheets. ex 3h 24m equals 3.4 I am not able to extract the minute part incorrectly.

I have tried the below functions which work well for the hour part but fail for the minute part.

```
=LEFT(c1, SEARCH("h",c1)-1)
```

---

```
=IFERROR((REGEXEXTRACT(D1,"([[:print:]]+)h")),0)
```

---

```
C        D
4h       2h 49m
32m 19s  2h 2m
6h 7m    3h 24m
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Harshcoder, have you had any chance of trying out my approach yet? Please provide feedback at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract hours, minutes and seconds into separate columns, you may use three separate `REGEXEXTRACT` formulas:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C1,"(\d+)h"), "")
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C1,"(\d+)m"), "")
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C1,"(\d+)s"), "")
```

Here, `(\d+)` is a capturing group that grabs 1 or more digits and the letter after is just matched, and thus, is not returned by the function.

You may also try to extract each part using optional patterns:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C1, "(?:(\d+)h)?\s*(?:(\d+)m)?\s*(?:(\d+)s)?")
```

Here, all hour, minute and second patterns are optional, and minutes will still match even if hours are missing.

**Details**

- `(?:(\d+)h)?` - an optional hour part wrapped with a non-capturing group:

  - `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
  - `h` - `h` letter
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:(\d+)m)?` - an optional minute part:

  - `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
  - `m` - `m` letter
- `(?:(\d+)s)?` - an optional seconds part:

  - `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
  - `s` - `s` letter